# How do I find the portion of a cell/voxel lying within a defined surface?

Tags: complex-geometry, integration, computational-geometry, surfaces

We have a 3-dimensional grid of voxels (or cells), with individual voxels being of volume $dx\,dy\,dz$ where $dx=dy=dz=1$.

A cone-like surface is defined by some function, $z = f(x, y)$, which in this case is specifically (where $\epsilon$, $w_0$ and $r_0$ are constants):

$$z=\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{w_0^2r_0^{-2\epsilon}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2\epsilon}}$$

Over the entire grid, how does one compute the fraction of each voxel's volume lying within the volume enclosed by that cone-like surface?

Obviously values should range from $0\rightarrow1$ and, in this particular case, voxels positioned at large values of $x$ and $y$ and small values of $z$ have none of their volume within the cone, while those lying at large values of $z$, and small values of $x$ and $y$ are completely enclosed by the cone-like surface.

Comment: I am guessing that you have a particular application in mind.  It would be helpful to explain that, and in particular, what level of accuracy you care about.  The issues here are probably more about efficient computation than any real mathematical complexity, so this site is probably not the best one for your question.  You could try math.stackexchange.com or scicomp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: A voxel is a cube, so you are asking for the intersection of a cube (aligned with the axis) and your function $f(x,y)$. Since a cube is defined by six planes, you need to compute the intersection of a plane with $f$, in particular, $f(x,c)$ for $y=c$ with $c$ a constant. The intersection curve is pretty simple, but in the end you will need to numerically approximate.